# Eclipse can not seem to understand newer features of C++

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, c++23

Eclipse's editor does not seem to understand newer features of C++23. Even though the build and run are successful.

Eclipse information:

```
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043
OS: Linux, v.6.8.0-rc7-eababneh, x86_64 / gtk 3.24.33
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java runtime version: 21.0.2+13-LTS-58
Java version: 21.0.2
```

How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need to update Eclipse and CDT? What version are you using? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, sorry. That somehow escaped me. I posted the info above.

Comment: Just because the compiler on your system understands the code does not imply that a totally unrelated program (namely Eclipse) also does -- someone has to teach Eclipse these features, and that may simply not have happened yet.